# How to smoothly minimize flying draggable popup with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I write some popup window, that will fly on the view part of page while scrolling them, window is also draggable.

See it below:

```js
 var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
 var $el = jq(".Box");
 var $btnmini = jq(".sessionCD #btnmin");
 var isMini = false; //Панелька минимизирована.

 $el.draggable({
   cursor: "grab",
   containment: 'window',
   drag: function(event,
     ui) {
     jq(this).css('cursor',
       'grabbing');
   },
   stop: function(event,
     ui) {
     jq(this).css('cursor',
       'grab');
   },

 });

jq("#btnmin").click(function () {
 if (isMini) {
     jq('.Box #content #msg').show();
        jq('.Box #content #note').show();
  isMini = false;
 } else {
        jq('.Box #content #msg').hide();
        jq('.Box #content #note').hide();
  isMini = true;
 }
});


 jq('#btn').click(function() {
   $el.show();
 });

 jq('#btntxt').click(function() {
   var i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     jq('#txt').append('<p>THIS IS SPARTA!!!</p>');
   }
 });

 jq(window).scroll(function() {
   $el.stop().animate({
     "top": (jq(window).scrollTop() + 10) + "px"
   }, "fast");
 });
```

```css
 .Box {
   cursor: "grab";
   position: absolute;
   left: 2px;
   top: 2px;
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
   display: none;
   margin: 1px;
   padding: 2px;
   z-index: 100000;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #AAA #CECECE #E6E6E6;
   background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #F1F1F1;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #CECECE inset;
   border-radius: 8px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .Box #header {
   height: 20px;
   background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #D4E8CD;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #83A478;
   color: #416833;
 }
 .Box #header #title {
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 .minibtn {
   margin-right: 2px;
 }
 .minibtn:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 .sessionCD #time {
   font-family: Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
   font-size: 19px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="Box" title="">
  <div id="header">
    <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="0px" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <col width="20px" />
        <col width="88%" />
        <col width="10%" />
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="piccha">
            <img src="dragger.png" />
          </td>
          <td id="title">
            User!
          </td>
          <td id="btnmin" class="minibtn">
            Mini
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p id="msg">text text text
      <br/>text text:</p>
    <span id="time">Super Numbers 12312</span>
    <br/>
    <p id="note">The note</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn">show box</button>
<button id="btntxt">add 30 text</button>

<div id="txt">

</div>
```

Also [avaliable on JSfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/arhangelsoft/4xatmnt7/1/)

**How I can minimize this window using "Mini" button with smooth effect?**
Under "minimize" I mean  smooth hide #msg and #note elements, after that smooth resize window. The same for "Maximize" but smooth showing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xatmnt7/2/

Comment: @Lucky, Yes, that's what I want. Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) for smoothly showing and hiding the div elements,

> The .slideUp() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up, appearing to conceal
>   the items. Once the height reaches 0 (or, if set, to whatever the CSS
>   min-height property is), the display style property is set to none to
>   ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.
>
> The .slideDown() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide down, making way for the
>   revealed items.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xatmnt7/2)

You can pass "slow" or "fast" or "duration" (time in milliseconds) to control the speed of the div displayed after click event.

**JQuery**

```
jq("#btnmin").click(function () {
    if (isMini) {
        jq('.Box #content #msg').slideDown();
        jq('.Box #content #note').slideDown();
        isMini = false;
    } else {
        jq('.Box #content #msg').slideUp();
        jq('.Box #content #note').slideUp();
        isMini = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it. it will work greatly:

```
jq("#btnmin").click(function () {
    if (isMini) {
        jq('.Box #content #msg').show(500);
        jq('.Box #content #note').show(500);
        isMini = false;
    } else {
        jq('.Box #content #msg').hide(500);
        jq('.Box #content #note').hide(500);
        isMini = true;
    }
});
```

To increase speed decrease value. like: 500 -> 300.

http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/4xatmnt7/3/